# find shortest paths from source to all vertices using Dijkstra’s Algorithm?

Tags: shortest-path, weighted-graphs, dijkstras-algorithm

For Dijkstra’s,i can find shortest paths from source to all vertices in the given graph ***but*** how can i calling the algorithm |V| times taking each vertex as a source and store all tables ???
For example :
What is the shortest path from 1 to 4? You need to print the value and the exact path vertices starting from 1 and ending at 4.

Comment: I think you need to provide more detail for us to understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming here that you want to calculate the all-pairs shortest paths for a graph using Dijkstra's.

First, to find the shortest path between all pairs of vertices, you can create a $ |V|^2 $ matrix where row and column *i* and *j* corresponds to the shortest distance from vertex *i* to vertex *j*.

Second, to mark the all-path shortest paths' path, you simply set the *parent* property of each vertex *j* to the current vertex *i* you are visiting from every time you have to relax the edge going to *j* from *i*. Keeping one set of vertices and edge will be sufficient as an APSP will also produce a tree, similar to a SSSP tree.

Comment: thank u ,, but how can i applied this using Dijkstra algorithm ? ... this algorithm take Array and the source vertex as a parameter .. so how can i store this in 2D array ?  :)

Comment: Can you be more specific regarding what is the array it takes in. Does it take in the adjacency list or an array of estimates to be updated?

Comment: it takes adjacency matrix ... so i wanna to store it in 2D array where i's takes the source vertices in each time and j's takes the value of the shortest path between i,j node ... are u understand what i mean ??

Comment: You can have 2 functions - the first is the actual Dijkstra algorithm which takes in the adjacency matrix and a source vertex i and run Dijkstra for all shortest paths from i. The second will be the driver which simply calls the first Dijkstra function on every node in the adjacency matrix.